# C# get column count and rows count for only valid range with interopExcel

Tags: c#, excel

I am working with Micorsoft Office interop Excel
Now my problem is when updated data cannot get correct rows and column count.

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(txtbTrainPath.Text);
Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;   
object[] cols = { 3 };
xlRange.RemoveDuplicates(cols);
rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
```

Now, here I cannot get updated rows count. I want after removed duplicate rows, then want to get rows count. Can you help me with than?

Comment: Add `xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;` again after `xlRange.RemoveDuplicates(cols);` and it should give you updated counts.

Comment: And please help me what is Type.missing i am not sure what is that and rols...

Comment: thanks quickly reply i will try now

Comment: Oh yes, thanks ManishChristian. it works, And please help me when once i press Enter at last of rows. It made much more rows. In that case i got almost much bigger count. Real rows count was 1000 but i got 45687.

Comment: Pls update your question with more details.

Comment: yes. my excel file has https://www.dropbox.com/s/betci638b1faw8g/Demo%20Training%20Data.xlsx?dl=0 please download

Comment: this file has only 1000 rows for valid datas but i got 49998

Comment: Update your question with more details instead of giving link to your file

Comment: https://codeshare.io/G8Xxqe

Comment: stackoverflow site said me i cannot move to discuss chat. https://codeshare.io/G8Xxqe please check this url for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141448/discussion-between-riguang-zheng-and-manishchristian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use this again every time. :)
   xlRange xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange